# Are integer reads atomic in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, mobile, concurrency, parallel-processing

For Delphi compilers from XE2 through to XE8, for non-windows target platforms, is the read operation of an integer data member, annotated with [Volatile], atomic?

I know for the case of windows platform, it is atomic if and only if the data member is aligned to 4 bytes, but what about non-windows (Android etc.)?

Please note, I am not asking about thread-safety. Thread-safety and atomicity are two different things.

Comment: @Ken-White: Please reopen. This question is not a duplicate.

Comment: See [Atomic vs. Non-Atomic Operations](http://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/). `"In practice, we usually know more about our target platforms than that. For example, it’s common knowledge that on all modern x86, x64, Itanium, SPARC, ARM and PowerPC processors, plain 32-bit integer assignment is atomic as long as the target variable is naturally aligned. You can verify it by consulting your processor manual and/or compiler documentation. In the games industry, I can tell you that a lot of 32-bit integer assignments rely on this particular guarantee."`

Comment: This depends on the number of write cycles to the memory. One cycle is atomic and more than one is not.

Comment: @LURD . Thanks LU. Your comment is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

LU RD 's comment is the correct answer.

Non-windows works similar to windows, in that the read operation is atomic if and only if the data member is 32 bit aligned. In then general case, you can't rely on it being atomic because you don't know the alignment, but in the specific case, where you control the declaration of the data member, you can use the {$ALIGN 4} or {$ALIGN 8} directives locally to guarantee alignment.

Example,

```
{$IFDEF POSIX}
{$ALIGN 4}
type
TMyClass = class
  [Volatile] FValue: integer;
  end;
{$ENDIF}
```

... in the above, FValue can be read atomically. (Not making any claims about thread-safety).

In the more general case, where the alignment of FValue is unknown, reading FValue might not always be atomic, and something similiar to the following code would be required ...

```
ReadOfValue := TInterlocked.CompareExchange( FValue, 0, 0);
```

The above has one caveat: The TInterlocked class may be not available to some compilers. I am not sure when it was introduced. Probably XE7.

---

### Update

Thanks to comments below from David Heffernan and Gabr, I declare above code will *not* reliably work on a non-windows platform. The only way to guarantee correct alignment is to use pointer arithmetic. The GpStuff unit in the [OmniThreadLibrary](https://github.com/gabr42/OmniThreadLibrary) effectively uses pointer arithmetic to provide an atomically readable integer value.

Possibly the [Volatile] attribute does not help, but you could also say it does no harm, and may even have a semantic benefit or code readers.

Comment: Aligning the field within the class or record is not enough. The containing structure, the class or record, must be aligned too. What guarantees does the compiler give for an automatic variable? None so far as I know. This is, sadly, an area where the language definition is totally lacking, and where the implementation is poor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Goodness! That is a pessimistic interpretation of $ALIGN. Records I understand, but for classes, if $ALIGN only guarentees  a fields alignment relative to the object base, rather than the absolute address, as you suggest, then this makes $ALIGN for classes completely pointless.The online help says ` fields in class structures are aligned on double-word boundaries`. I suppose that is open to interpretation. I'll try an Embarcadero forum for clarifcation.

Comment: You shouldn't be using $ALIGN 4 anyway. You don't want that. You don't want to misalign doubles for instance. You want the default option which is $ALIGN ON, equal to $ALIGN 8. Embarcadero have documented this poorly, and implemented it badly. Alignment for heap allocated structures is determined by memory manager settings. It is 8 by default IIRC. For automatic storage, I think you will find that it is perfectly possible for types with alignment 8, e.g. double, to be mis-aligned. Try declaring some double local variables, mixed in with some booleans.

Comment: I don't think it's pessimistic at all. My development is in the floating point arena, where perf matters to me. And my experience is that Delphi routinely misaligns my data. It is very depressing.

Comment: You can ask on the Embarcadero forum, but is anybody there, and is it ever up? My opinion is that you get a better answer if you ask here. What's more, people can benefit in the future. Otherwise others are destined to ask the same question again and again and again.

Comment: TInterlocked will not help you if the value is not correctly aligned. Even on Windows a behaviour of any Interlocked* function is undefined if alignment is not correct.