# is reading/writing an integer (4 bytes) atomic on ios/android like on win32/win64?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

On windows, if align is set to 4 bytes (this is by default in project option) then reading/writing to an integer is atomic. Is it the same on ios/android ?

if not atomic, can i have an exception or a misc error (other than obtening the wrong value) if 2 threads read and write at the same time the same integer value ?

Comment: See [Are integer reads atomic in Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29958168/576719).

Comment: thanks LU :) yes it this :) so as conclusion reading writing on integer is not atomic under ios/android :( ... can i have exception (other than retrieve the wrong value) if 2 thread read and write at the same time the same integer value ?

Comment: Even on Windows, It is not guaranteed to be atomic if the data is not aligned properly. And no, there is no way to get an exception raised if one thread reads from memory that another thread is still writing to. If you want to ensure the correct value is read/written, you have to use proper multi-thread locking code, such as by using a `TCriticalSection`.