# Potential Race Condition in TNetEncoding.GetBase64Encoding?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, race-condition, delphi-multithreading

I came across a piece of code in the Delphi source that has raised some questions regarding its thread safety in a multi-threaded environment. The code is as follows:

```
class function TNetEncoding.GetBase64Encoding: TNetEncoding;
var
  LEncoding: TBase64Encoding;
begin
  if FBase64Encoding = nil then
  begin
    LEncoding := TBase64Encoding.Create;
    if AtomicCmpExchange(Pointer(FBase64Encoding), Pointer(LEncoding), nil) <> nil then
      LEncoding.Free
  end;
  Result := FBase64Encoding;
end;
```

My concern revolves around the multi-threaded behavior of this code. Specifically, is there a potential race condition between two threads executing this function simultaneously?

For instance, consider the following scenario:

- **Thread 1** executes `AtomicCmpExchange(Pointer(FBase64Encoding), Pointer(LEncoding), nil)`.
- **Thread 2** then reaches the `if FBase64Encoding = nil` check and finds it to be false, indicating that `FBase64Encoding` is ready for use. However, my concern is whether it's guaranteed that `FBase64Encoding` is fully valid at this point. Is there a possibility that Thread 1's `AtomicCmpExchange` operation has not completely finished writing all the data to `FBase64Encoding`? In other words, can Thread 2 confidently use `FBase64Encoding` immediately after the check, or is there a risk of accessing a partially written pointer?

Any insights on whether this code can lead to a race condition and, if so, how it might be mitigated, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The whole point of using `AtomicCmpExchange()` is that `FBase64Encoding` is compared and updated *atomicly*, so it can't be a partial value. And `FBase64Encoding` is aligned in memory so reading from it is atomic by the memory bus. If 2 or more threads try to run this code concurrently, the result is guaranteed to be consistent and expected.

Comment: What did you think the documentation meant? I mean, you did look at the documentation?

Comment: thanks @RemyLebeau, I Updated my question. when you say that FBase64Encoding is aligned in memory so reading from it is atomic by the memory bus. Is this guaranteed to be the case in all platform and in all case ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan With documentation? from what I read from one of your previous contribution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958168/are-integer-reads-atomic-in-delphi) : in general case, you can't rely on Integer being atomic because you don't know the alignment.

Comment: @zeus yes, it is safe and guaranteed by the underlying platform. `FBase64Encoding` will always be read as a whole value, and will always be written as a whole value. It will never contain a partial value, like you are concerned about.

Comment: So you didn't read the documentation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry i didn't find any documentation that say writing and reading to 64 bit values (ie: pointer) are atomic in all 64 bit platforms (ios, android, linux, etc.). I would love to find such confirmation in the doc

Comment: Isn't that what the documentation for AtomicCmpExchange says?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but the problem is not about AtomicCmpExchange, of course i know that AtomicCmpExchange is atomic that not the problem, i just worried that I mix writing the in64 value via AtomicCmpExchange  and reading it directly via the member field. and this their is no documentation that say it's permitted and safe (as far as i know)

Comment: So is your question "can tearing occur" for aligned data? And for what it's worth, I don't understand why you focus on 64 bit. What makes you think that 32 bit is OK, but things are different on 64 bit?

Comment: Naturally aligned pointer size reads and writes are always atomic. So that means 32-bit read/write will be atomic on 32-bit platform and 64-bit read/write will be atomic on 64-bit platform. What is not atomic is 64-bit read/write on 32-bit platform.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar but what if i have : TpackedRecord = packed record
    FBool: Boolean;
    Fint64: int64;
  end;

in this case Fint64 is not aligned, but i can not explain why the read/write is still atomic on 64 bit platform (I did the test) :(

Comment: Nobody said that tearing of non-aligned data will happen in a predictable way. The only thing that is promised is that aligned data won't tear. Why do you care about non-aligned data? What has that got to do with this question?

Comment: If you have non-aligned data then tearing may occur. But that is whole different question. Not the one you asked here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan nothing with this question, I was just curious why even with non aligned data (like  TpackedRecord = packed record FBool: Boolean; Fint64: int64; end; ) I can not simulate  any error :(

Comment: @zeus does your non aligned data cross a cache line, because that's the actual mechanism for tearing in the architectures I am familiar with. Again, if you did some websearch with these keywords you'd find this info out. My advice to you is to work hard on improving your websearch.

Answer (score 4):

The code in question is thread safe.

There is a possibility that two or more threads will pass the `nil` comparison:

```
if FBase64Encoding = nil then
```

In that case, more than one thread will construct `TBase64Encoding` instance and assign that instance to local variable `LEncoding`.

However, only one of those threads will successfully assign the value in local `LEncoding` variable to the `FBase64Encoding` field because `AtomicCmpExchange` will atomically perform comparison and assignment. This is the whole purpose of `AtomicXXX` functions.

After the one thread assigns the value to `FBase64Encoding`, `AtomicCmpExchange` will fail for all other threads (it will return current content of the `FBase64Encoding` which in that case will be non `nil` value) and then encoding instance constructed by that thread which is not needed will be released with `LEncoding.Free`.

The only consequence of this code is that maybe some extra encoding instances will be constructed and those that are not needed will be immediately released.

If you are using this kind of lazy initialization in your code, you need to pay attention that created instances are not too resource heavy and, more importantly, that they can be properly constructed without raising an exception which could then have negative impact on the code in the thread where exception happened.

If you take a look at official documentation you will see that `AtomicCmpExchange` does comparison and exchange in thread-safe manner.

[System.AtomicCmpExchange](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.AtomicCmpExchange)

> Atomic intrinsic Compare and Exchange function compares the contents
> of the Target to a given value (Comparand) and, only if they are the
> same, modifies the contents of Target　to the new value.
>
> This function always returns the original value of Target.
> ...
>
> AtomicCmpExchange is used for comparing and exchanging memory values.
>
> Atomic operations are used to:
>
> - Implement multi-threaded locking primitives
> - Provide the primitives necessary for implementing so-called "lock-free" structures

Comment: Thanks @dalija. However, I'm concerned about the atomicity of operations involving FBase64Encoding, which is a 64-bit pointer (on a 64-bit OS). My worry is that during the AtomicCmpExchange operation, the first 32 bits of the pointer might be written first, rendering FBase64Encoding non-null but not yet fully valid. If another thread accesses FBase64Encoding at this exact moment, it could pass the if FBase64Encoding <> nil check, but the pointer value might still be incomplete and incorrect. are 64-bit read / write operations atomic across all platforms?

Comment: AtomicCmpExchange is safe on all platforms. The compiler generates the correct instructions for the platform. If Pointer is 64-bits, then the compiler will generate 64-bit atomic operations. Likewise, for 32-bit platforms, the compiler will use 32-bit atomic operations.

AtomicCmpExchange() isn't a "function" per-se; it is a compiler intrinsic which the compiler knows about explicitly and will generate the correct instructions in-line without a function call. IOW, you won't find an actual function implementation for AtomicCmpExchange().

Comment: thanks @AllenBauer but if AtomicCmpExchange is doing "if FBase64Encoding = nil" safe also ? especially on 64 bit plateform ?

Comment: Yes. AtomicCmpExchange will "stall" any other thread that is in the process of accessing FBase64Encoding until the AtomicCmpExchange operation is complete. The term "atomic" in this context means that the operation cannot be broken down any further such that other processor cores (threads) can "see" any intermediate state. 64bit platforms behave no differently than 32bit platforms except that the natural "word" size is 64 instead of 32.